# Why is my for loop skipping certain values in my python index generator?

Tags: python, for-loop, indexing, data-retrieval

I am writing a python search engine that reads a list of jokes, tokenizes the words, creates an index (key:words,values:document ids of the document(s) the word appears in, and then searches the index. The tokenization and search methods work fine, but my indexing method is giving me issues and I can't figure out why.

**Code**

```
def create_index(tokens):
    lst = -1
    duplicates =[]
    index = {}
    docnum = len(tokens)
    for list in tokens:
        lst += 1
        xst = -1
        for x in list:
            xst += 1
            element = tokens[lst][xst]
            value = ""
            elin = 0
            if element not in duplicates:
                for r in range(docnum):
                    if element in tokens[r]:
                        if elin > 0:
                            value += " "
                        value += "%d" % r
                        elin += 1

                        print(tokens[r])
                        print(r)
                if len(value) > 1:
                    index[element] = value.split()
                    duplicates += element
                else:
                    index[element] = value
                    duplicates += element
    return index
```

the print statements are there just so I could see where the problem lies, and indeed I saw that certain r values in the for loop are being skipped entirely. I'm pretty sure I'm not modifying what I'm iterating over, which I believe is what usually causes for loops to skip.

**Input (tokens)**

```
[['What', 'did', 'the', 'little', 'boy', 'tell', 'the', 'game', 'warden', 'His', 'dad', 'was', 'in', 'the', 'kitchen', 'poaching', 'eggs'], ['What', 'do', 'you', 'call', 'a', 'chicken', 'crossing', 'the', 'road', 'Poultry', 'in', 'motion'], ['What', 'do', 'you', 'call', 'it', 'when', 'a', 'cat', 'sues', 'another', 'cat', 'A', 'Clawsuit'], ['What', 'does', 'an', 'envelope', 'say', 'when', 'you', 'lick', 'it', 'Nothing', 'It', 'just', 'shuts', 'up'], ['How', 'can', 'you', 'tell', 'the', 'ocean', 'is', 'friendly', 'It', 'waves'], ['What', 's', 'black', 'white', 'green', 'and', 'bumpy', 'A', 'pickle', 'wearing', 'a', 'tuxedo'], ['When', 'was', 'meat', 'so', 'high', 'When', 'the', 'cow', 'jumped', 'over', 'the', 'moon'], ['What', 'happened', 'to', 'the', 'wind', 'It', 'blew', 'away'], ['What', 'starts', 'with', 'T', 'is', 'full', 'of', 'T', 'and', 'ends', 'with', 'T', 'A', 'teapot'], ['What', 'is', 'a', 'hermit', 'A', 'girl', 's', 'baseball', 'glove'], ['What', 'does', 'a', 'television', 'have', 'in', 'common', 'with', 'a', 'rabbit', 'His', 'ears'], ['What', 'did', 'the', 'crop', 'say', 'to', 'the', 'farmer', 'Why', 'are', 'you', 'always', 'picking', 'on', 'me'], ['What', 'did', 'the', 'guy', 'say', 'when', 'he', 'walked', 'into', 'the', 'bar', 'Ouch'], ['How', 'is', 'a', 'locksmith', 'like', 'a', 'typewritter', 'They', 'both', 'have', 'a', 'lot', 'of', 'keys'], ['What', 'has', 'four', 'legs', 'and', 'goes', 'booo', 'A', 'cow', 'with', 'a', 'cold'], ['What', 'is', 'a', 'caterpillar', 'afraid', 'of', 'A', 'dogerpillar'], ['Who', 'has', 'the', 'strongest', 'underwear', 'Arnold', 'Shortsineger'], ['Why', 'did', 'the', 'elephant', 'decide', 'not', 'to', 'move', 'Because', 'he', 'couldn', 't', 'lift', 'his', 'trunk'], ['Which', 'are', 'the', 'stronger', 'days', 'of', 'the', 'week', 'Saturday', 'and', 'Sunday', 'The', 'rest', 'are', 'weekdays'], ['Which', 'runs', 'faster', 'hot', 'or', 'cold', 'Hot', 'Everyone', 'can', 'catch', 'a', 'cold'], ['Why', 'did', 'the', 'strawberry', 'cross', 'the', 'road', 'Because', 'his', 'mother', 'was', 'in', 'a', 'jam'], ['How', 'do', 'you', 'keep', 'a', 'lion', 'from', 'charging', 'Take', 'away', 'its', 'credit', 'cards'], ['What', 'do', 'you', 'call', 'a', 'cow', 'with', 'a', 'twitch', 'Beef', 'jerky'], ['What', 'is', 'the', 'best', 'way', 'to', 'keep', 'water', 'from', 'running', 'Don', 't', 'pay', 'the', 'water', 'bill'], ['Where', 'do', 'cows', 'go', 'to', 'have', 'fun', 'The', 'moovies'], ['What', 'time', 'was', 'is', 'when', 'the', 'elephant', 'sat', 'on', 'a', 'chair', 'Time', 'to', 'get', 'a', 'new', 'chair'], ['What', 'did', 'the', 'flower', 'say', 'to', 'the', 'bike', 'Petal'], ['Why', 'do', 'we', 'not', 'tell', 'secrets', 'in', 'a', 'corn', 'patch', 'Too', 'many', 'ears'], ['What', 's', 'yellow', 'and', 'writes', 'A', 'ball', 'point', 'banana'], ['Did', 'people', 'laugh', 'when', 'the', 'lady', 'fell', 'on', 'the', 'ice', 'No', 'but', 'the', 'ice', 'cracked', 'up'], ['What', 'word', 'is', 'always', 'spelled', 'incorrectly', 'Incorrectly'], ['What', 'should', 'you', 'do', 'if', 'your', 'dog', 'is', 'missing', 'Check', 'the', 'Lost', 'and', 'Hound'], ['What', 'have', 'you', 'seen', 'that', 'you', 'will', 'never', 'see', 'again', 'Yesterday'], ['Why', 'did', 'the', 'turkey', 'cross', 'the', 'road', 'To', 'get', 'to', 'the', 'chicken'], ['Why', 'was', 'Cinderella', 'Late', 'for', 'the', 'ball', 'She', 'forgot', 'to', 'swing', 'the', 'bat'], ['How', 'can', 'you', 'tell', 'there', 's', 'a', 'hippo', 'in', 'your', 'oven', 'The', 'oven', 'door', 'won', 't', 'close'], ['What', 'do', 'you', 'get', 'when', 'you', 'cross', 'a', 'shark', 'and', 'Flipper', 'A', 'fat', 'shark'], ['What', 'did', 'the', 'lamp', 'say', 'to', 'the', 'other', 'lamp', 'You', 'turn', 'me', 'on'], ['What', 'did', 'the', 'sidewalk', 'do', 'when', 'he', 'heard', 'a', 'funny', 'joke', 'He', 'cracked', 'up'], ['Why', 'did', 'the', 'chicken', 'cross', 'the', 'road', 'He', 'wanted', 'to', 'prove', 'to', 'the', 'armadillo', 'that', 'it', 'could', 'be', 'done'], ['Why', 'did', 'the', 'dalmation', 'need', 'glasses', 'He', 'was', 'seeing', 'spots'], ['What', 'did', 'the', 'book', 'say', 'to', 'the', 'page', 'Don', 't', 'turn', 'away', 'from', 'me'], ['What', 'do', 'you', 'call', 'a', 'pig', 'in', 'a', 'butcher', 'shop', 'A', 'pork', 'chop'], ['In', 'France', 'what', 'do', 'frogs', 'eat', 'French', 'Flies'], ['What', 'is', 'yellow', 'and', 'wears', 'a', 'mask', 'The', 'Lone', 'Lemon'], ['What', 'do', 'astronauts', 'eat', 'for', 'dinner', 'Launch', 'meat'], ['Why', 'is', 'the', 'little', 'duck', 'always', 'so', 'sad', 'Because', 'he', 'always', 'sees', 'a', 'bill', 'in', 'front', 'of', 'his', 'face'], ['What', 'did', 'they', 'digital', 'clock', 'say', 'to', 'its', 'mom', 'Look', 'mom', 'no', 'hands'], ['What', 'is', 'the', 'best', 'way', 'to', 'raise', 'a', 'child', 'In', 'an', 'elevator'], ['What', 'is', 'always', 'behind', 'the', 'time', 'The', 'back', 'of', 'the', 'clock'], ['What', 's', 'green', 'and', 'sings', 'Elvis', 'Parsley'], ['What', 'has', '10', 'letters', 'and', 'starts', 'with', 'gas', 'An', 'automobile'], ['Why', 'did', 'they', 'bury', 'the', 'battery', 'Because', 'it', 'was', 'dead'], ['Why', 'did', 'the', 'chicken', 'go', 'to', 'the', 'library', 'To', 'check', 'out', 'a', 'bawk', 'bawk', 'bawkbawk'], ['If', 'a', 'woodchuck', 'had', 'a', 'name', 'what', 'would', 'it', 'be', 'Chuck', 'Wood'], ['How', 'do', 'you', 'catch', 'a', 'squirrel', 'Climb', 'a', 'tree', 'and', 'act', 'like', 'a', 'nut'], ['What', 'did', 'one', 'penny', 'say', 'to', 'the', 'other', 'Let', 's', 'get', 'together', 'and', 'make', 'some', 'sense'], ['Why', 'don', 't', 'lobsters', 'share', 'Because', 'they', 'are', 'shellfish'], ['Why', 'does', 'the', 'man', 'wish', 'he', 'could', 'be', 'a', 'guitar', 'player', 'in', 'a', 'room', 'full', 'of', 'beautiful', 'girls', 'Because', 'if', 'he', 'was', 'a', 'guitar', 'player', 'he', 'would', 'have', 'his', 'pick'], ['What', 'is', 'a', 'cat', 's', 'favorite', 'color', 'Purrple'], ['Why', 'did', 'the', 'ghost', 'float', 'across', 'the', 'road', 'Because', 'he', 'couldn', 't', 'walk'], ['What', 'kind', 'of', 'star', 'could', 'hurt', 'you', 'A', 'shooting', 'star']]
```

**Output (shortened)**

```
['What', 'did', 'the', 'little', 'boy', 'tell', 'the', 'game', 'warden', 'His', 'dad', 'was', 'in', 'the', 'kitchen', 'poaching', 'eggs']
0
['What', 'do', 'you', 'call', 'a', 'chicken', 'crossing', 'the', 'road', 'Poultry', 'in', 'motion']
1
['What', 'do', 'you', 'call', 'it', 'when', 'a', 'cat', 'sues', 'another', 'cat', 'A', 'Clawsuit']
2
['What', 'does', 'an', 'envelope', 'say', 'when', 'you', 'lick', 'it', 'Nothing', 'It', 'just', 'shuts', 'up']
3
['What', 's', 'black', 'white', 'green', 'and', 'bumpy', 'A', 'pickle', 'wearing', 'a', 'tuxedo']
5
['What', 'happened', 'to', 'the', 'wind', 'It', 'blew', 'away']
7
['What', 'starts', 'with', 'T', 'is', 'full', 'of', 'T', 'and', 'ends', 'with', 'T', 'A', 'teapot']
8
['What', 'is', 'a', 'hermit', 'A', 'girl', 's', 'baseball', 'glove']
9
['What', 'does', 'a', 'television', 'have', 'in', 'common', 'with', 'a', 'rabbit', 'His', 'ears']
10
['What', 'did', 'the', 'crop', 'say', 'to', 'the', 'farmer', 'Why', 'are', 'you', 'always', 'picking', 'on', 'me']
11
['What', 'did', 'the', 'guy', 'say', 'when', 'he', 'walked', 'into', 'the', 'bar', 'Ouch']
12
['What', 'has', 'four', 'legs', 'and', 'goes', 'booo', 'A', 'cow', 'with', 'a', 'cold']
14
['What', 'is', 'a', 'caterpillar', 'afraid', 'of', 'A', 'dogerpillar']
15
['What', 'do', 'you', 'call', 'a', 'cow', 'with', 'a', 'twitch', 'Beef', 'jerky']
22
['What', 'is', 'the', 'best', 'way', 'to', 'keep', 'water', 'from', 'running', 'Don', 't', 'pay', 'the', 'water', 'bill']
23
['What', 'time', 'was', 'is', 'when', 'the', 'elephant', 'sat', 'on', 'a', 'chair', 'Time', 'to', 'get', 'a', 'new', 'chair']
25
['What', 'did', 'the', 'flower', 'say', 'to', 'the', 'bike', 'Petal']
26
['What', 's', 'yellow', 'and', 'writes', 'A', 'ball', 'point', 'banana']
28
['What', 'word', 'is', 'always', 'spelled', 'incorrectly', 'Incorrectly']
30
```

With the input being a list of lists, the idea is to search through and put every unique word in as a key, with values being the documents it appears in. However the index produced

**Index**

```
{'walked': ['12'], 'across': ['60'], 'incorrectly': ['30'], 'Nothing': '3', 'keys': ['13'], 'frogs': ['43'], 'meat': ['6', '45'], 'be': ['39', '54', '58'], 'mother': ['20'], 'Petal': ['26'], 'typewritter': ['13'], 'see': ['32'], 'keep': ['21', '23'], 'jam': ['20'], 'black': '5', 'lick': '3', 'girls': ['58'], 'sues': '2', 'sidewalk': ['38'], 'book': ['41'], 'strongest': ['16'], 'shop': ['42'], 'favorite': ['59'], 'A': ['2', '5', '8', '9', '14', '15', '28', '36', '42', '61'], 'seen': ['32'], 'Did': ['29'], 'glove': '9', 'hands': ['47'], 'room': ['58'], 'patch': ['27'], 'T': '8', 'legs': ['14'], 'hippo': ['35'], 'his': ['17', '20', '46', '58'], 'cows': ['24'], 'new': ['25'], 'cards': ['21'], 'you': ['1', '2', '3', '4', '11', '21', '22', '31', '32', '35', '36', '42', '55', '61'], 'Look': ['47'], 'tree': ['55'], 'tell': ['0', '4', '27', '35'], 'missing': ['31'], 'front': ['46'], 'lion': ['21'], 'automobile': ['51'], 'eggs': '0', 'spots': ['40'], 'water': ['23'], 'full': ['8', '58'], 'moon': '6', 'need': ['40'], 'When': '6', 'moovies': ['24'], 'rest': ['18'], 'cat': ['2', '59'], 'boy': '0', 'fell': ['29'], 'hermit': '9', 'dogerpillar': ['15'], 'sings': ['50'], 'couldn': ['17', '60'], 'dad': '0', 'clock': ['47', '49'], 'turkey': ['33'], 'sat': ['25'], 'He': ['38', '39', '40'], 'bike': ['26'], 'seeing': ['40'], 'elevator': ['48'], 'Parsley': ['50'], 'secrets': ['27'], 'They': ['13'], 'flower': ['26'], 'both': ['13'], 'close': ['35'], 'bill': ['23', '46'], 'crossing': '1', 'glasses': ['40'], 'bawkbawk': ['53'], 'many': ['27'], 'penny': ['56'], 'guy': ['12'], 'chop': ['42'], 'had': ['54'], 'oven': ['35'], 'are': ['11', '18', '57'], 'jerky': ['22'], 'some': ['56'], 'Launch': ['45'], 'Ouch': ['12'], 'An': ['51'], 'Where': ['24'], 'caterpillar': ['15'], 'faster': ['19'], 'do': ['1', '2', '21', '22', '24', '27', '31', '36', '38', '42', '43', '45', '55'], 'lamp': ['37'], 'white': '5', 'Hot': ['19'], 'friendly': '4', 'pick': ['58'], 'me': ['11', '37', '41'], 'high': '6', 'always': ['11', '30', '46', '49'], 'crop': ['11'], 'face': ['46'], 'In': ['43', '48'], 'sad': ['46'], 'spelled': ['30'], 'poaching': '0', 'color': ['59'], 'twitch': ['22'], 'To': ['33', '53'], 'door': ['35'], 'Lemon': ['44'], 'jumped': '6', 'lobsters': ['57'], 'raise': ['48'], 'armadillo': ['39'], 'locksmith': ['13'], 'bawk': ['53'], 'It': ['3', '4', '7'], 'astronauts': ['45'], 'Flies': ['43'], 'Too': ['27'], 'digital': ['47'], 'Because': ['17', '20', '46', '52', '57', '58', '60'], 'joke': ['38'], 'ocean': '4', 'make': ['56'], 'hurt': ['61'], 'go': ['24', '53'], 'four': ['14'], 'with': ['8', '10', '14', '22', '51'], 'You': ['37'], 'laugh': ['29'], 'Don': ['23', '41'], 'Hound': ['31'], 'tuxedo': '5', 'farmer': ['11'], 'yellow': ['28', '44'], 'that': ['32', '39'], 'Wood': ['54'], 'if': ['31', '58'], 'eat': ['43', '45'], 'star': ['61'], 'happened': '7', 'catch': ['19', '55'], 'again': ['32'], 'check': ['53'], 'trunk': ['17'], 'together': ['56'], 'what': ['43', '54'], 'ice': ['29'], 'cross': ['20', '33', '36', '39'], 'banana': ['28'], 'mask': ['44'], 'Time': ['25'], 'Incorrectly': ['30'], 'underwear': ['16'], 'goes': ['14'], 'Cinderella': ['34'], 'they': ['47', '52', '57'], 'does': ['3', '10', '58'], 'child': ['48'], 'is': ['4', '8', '9', '13', '15', '23', '25', '30', '31', '44', '46', '48', '49', '59'], 'lady': ['29'], 'game': '0', 'the': ['0', '1', '4', '6', '7', '11', '12', '16', '17', '18', '20', '23', '25', '26', '29', '31', '33', '34', '37', '38', '39', '40', '41', '46', '48', '49', '52', '53', '56', '58', '60'], 'chicken': ['1', '33', '39', '53'], 'float': ['60'], 'His': ['0', '10'], 'mom': ['47'], '10': ['51'], 'people': ['29'], 'elephant': ['17', '25'], 'one': ['56'], 'will': ['32'], 'wish': ['58'], 'television': ['10'], 'can': ['4', '19', '35'], 'ends': '8', 'duck': ['46'], 'fat': ['36'], 'chair': ['25'], 'Clawsuit': '2', 'kind': ['61'], 'common': ['10'], 'its': ['21', '47'], 'wind': '7', 'shooting': ['61'], 'best': ['23', '48'], 'time': ['25', '49'], 'Poultry': '1', 'no': ['47'], 'not': ['17', '27'], 'picking': ['11'], 'won': ['35'], 'sees': ['46'], 'on': ['11', '25', '29', '37'], 'funny': ['38'], 'pig': ['42'], 'of': ['8', '13', '15', '18', '46', '49', '58', '61'], 'behind': ['49'], 'an': ['3', '48'], 'little': ['0', '46'], 'word': ['30'], 'point': ['28'], 'get': ['25', '33', '36', '56'], 'don': ['57'], 'could': ['39', '58', '61'], 'in': ['0', '1', '10', '20', '27', '35', '42', '46', '58'], 'away': ['7', '21', '41'], 'Everyone': ['19'], 'Let': ['56'], 'swing': ['34'], 'it': ['2', '3', '39', '52', '54'], 'Late': ['34'], 'way': ['23', '48'], 'rabbit': ['10'], 'to': ['7', '11', '17', '23', '24', '25', '26', '33', '34', '37', '39', '41', '47', '48', '53', '56'], 'have': ['10', '13', '24', '32', '58'], 'just': '3', 'heard': ['38'], 'over': '6', 'shark': ['36'], 'so': ['6', '46'], 'teapot': '8', 'strawberry': ['20'], 'from': ['21', '23', '41'], 'call': ['1', '2', '22', '42'], 'Lone': ['44'], 'weekdays': ['18'], 'ghost': ['60'], 'bumpy': '5', 'or': ['19'], 'girl': '9', 'Chuck': ['54'], 'guitar': ['58'], 'we': ['27'], 'Why': ['11', '17', '20', '27', '33', '34', '39', '40', '46', '52', '53', '57', '58', '60'], 'bat': ['34'], 'there': ['35'], 'The': ['18', '24', '35', '44', '49'], 'your': ['31', '35'], 'would': ['54', '58'], 'act': ['55'], 'writes': ['28'], 'No': ['29'], 'pickle': '5', 'beautiful': ['58'], 'running': ['23'], 'corn': ['27'], 'week': ['18'], 'wears': ['44'], 'French': ['43'], 'walk': ['60'], 'name': ['54'], 'sense': ['56'], 'never': ['32'], 'Take': ['21'], 'out': ['53'], 'woodchuck': ['54'], 'pay': ['23'], 'shellfish': ['57'], 'cold': ['14', '19'], 'letters': ['51'], 'butcher': ['42'], 'another': '2', 'runs': ['19'], 'ball': ['28', '34'], 'Sunday': ['18'], 'up': ['3', '29', '38'], 'like': ['13', '55'], 'page': ['41'], 'man': ['58'], 'If': ['54'], 'Which': ['18', '19'], 'nut': ['55'], 'share': ['57'], 'say': ['3', '11', '12', '26', '37', '41', '47', '56'], 'How': ['4', '13', '21', '35', '55'], 'Beef': ['22'], 'wanted': ['39'], 'dalmation': ['40'], 'baseball': '9', 'dinner': ['45'], 'ears': ['10', '27'], 'What': ['0', '1', '2', '3', '5', '7', '8', '9', '10', '11', '12', '14', '15', '22', '23', '25', '26', '28', '30', '31', '32', '36', '37', '38', '41', '42', '44', '45', '47', '48', '49', '50', '51', '56', '59', '61'], 'has': ['14', '16', '51'], 'prove': ['39'], 'Lost': ['31'], 'road': ['1', '20', '33', '39', '60'], 'green': ['5', '50'], 'wearing': '5', 'fun': ['24'], 'move': ['17'], 'cracked': ['29', '38'], 'shuts': '3', 'was': ['0', '6', '20', '25', '34', '40', '52', '58'], 'blew': '7', 'stronger': ['18'], 'Climb': ['55'], 'motion': '1', 'decide': ['17'], 'kitchen': '0', 'turn': ['37', '41'], 'cow': ['6', '14', '22'], 'he': ['12', '17', '38', '46', '58', '60'], 'days': ['18'], 'Yesterday': ['32'], 'envelope': '3', 'Arnold': ['16'], 'hot': ['19'], 'waves': '4', 'She': ['34'], 'bury': ['52'], 'pork': ['42'], 'afraid': ['15'], 'when': ['2', '3', '12', '25', '29', '36', '38'], 'other': ['37', '56'], 'warden': '0', 'did': ['0', '11', '12', '17', '20', '26', '33', '37', '38', '39', '40', '41', '47', '52', '53', '56', '60'], 'Purrple': ['59'], 'forgot': ['34'], 'Check': ['31'], 'charging': ['21'], 'and': ['5', '8', '14', '18', '28', '31', '36', '44', '50', '51', '55', '56'], 'player': ['58'], 'gas': ['51'], 'for': ['34', '45'], 'dog': ['31'], 'Flipper': ['36'], 'Elvis': ['50'], 'library': ['53'], 'credit': ['21'], 'Shortsineger': ['16'], 'but': ['29'], 'battery': ['52'], 'lot': ['13'], 'lift': ['17'], 'booo': ['14'], 'Who': ['16'], 'Saturday': ['18'], 'back': ['49'], 'should': ['31'], 'starts': ['8', '51'], 'done': ['39'], 'France': ['43'], 'squirrel': ['55'], 'into': ['12'], 'dead': ['52'], 'bar': ['12']}
```

is incorrect because my for loop is skipping steps. Is it possible that the amount of looping being done is messing with the loop? After adding the two print statements for debugging the output was 11373 lines long. If so, can anyone recommend a better alternative? Apologies if I'm missing an obvious answer.

Comment: BTW using for variables builtin names like `list` is a bad idea

Comment: Your loop is not skipping steps. If some value of `r` is not printed It's just because it does not meet the condition `element in tokens[r]`.

Comment: @Goyo you're probably right and I messed up somewhere, however when I review the input everything seems to be where it should be, it just doesn't show.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand you correctly, but:

```
from collections import defaultdict

def create_index(tokens):
    index = defaultdict(list)

    for docid, ls in enumerate(tokens):
        for word in set(ls):
            index[word].append(docid)
    return index
```

That makes `index` a dictionary from words to lists of document ids:

```
>>> tokens = ["this is a test".split(), "that is another test".split()]
>>> create_index(tokens)
defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {'test': [0, 1], 'is': [0, 1], 'this': [0], 'that': [1], 'a': [0], 'another': [1]})
```

Comment: My goal is to  make a dictionary called index in which the keys are words, and the values are the document ids for the documents in which the word appears. For example, if the word apple appeared in three different documents, I want the index to read {'apple':[0,1,2]}. Your code gave me an interesting idea, but it only has a single doc_id for any given word

Comment: No it doesn't, for example `index['he']` is `[12, 17, 38, 46, 58, 60]` afterwards.

Comment: But I thought that .append was only for lists? Also, I am now getting a KeyError.

Comment: @TechSavvySmurf Yes, it is appending to the list inside, that's the magic of `defaultdict`. I added a minimal example at the end.

Comment: Sorry, I was commenting at the same time you made the edits, it works now.